# how to use ngif with values chosen from the drop down list above?

Tags: material-design, angular8, angular-ng-if

What I want to achieve is that, if the user select the roles (multiselect) then the roles array includes `superadmin`, then I want to hide the element. The code I might use is
`*ngIf="roles.include(x.name !=='superadmin')"`  but it doesn't work!. 
What might be the solution for that?

```
<div
   class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile"
   >
   <mat-form-field
      class="mat-form-field-fluid"
      >
      <mat-select
      placeholder="Role"
      formControlName="roles"
      multiple
      [(ngModel)]="checkedRoles"
      >
      <mat-option
      *ngFor="
      let role of userRoles"
      [value]="role"
      >
      {{role.name}}
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error
         *ngIf="
         isControlHasError(
         'roles',
         'required'
         )
         "
         >
         <strong>{{
         "AUTH.VALIDATION.REQUIRED_FIELD"
         | translate
         }}</strong>
      </mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
<!-- clientele starts -->
<div
   class="col-lg-6 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile"  
   *ngIf="roles.include(x.name !=='superadmin')"
   >
   <mat-form-field
      class="mat-form-field-fluid"
      >
      <mat-select
      matTooltip="if you are creating a user for admin or superadmin, leave it empty"
      placeholder="Clientele"
      formControlName="clientele"
      [(ngModel)]="checkedClientele"
      >
      <mat-option
      *ngFor="
      let clientele of clienteles"
      [value]="clientele"
      >
      {{ clientele.Name }}
      </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
</div>
```